# C# - modify button.click event to pass data?

Tags: c#, events

I am programatically creating buttons and each button has a tag binary array. While creating I am binding an event `Button.Click` but I do not know how to add parameter since the event handler is already prepared. I would need to pass the tag of the button to method that is called by that event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to pass the tag of the button - the button is provided as the sender, so you can get at the tag directly:

```
private void HandleButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button) sender;
    object tag = button.Tag;
    ...
}
```

Another alternative is to wire up the event manually with an anonymous method or lambda expression, which lets you call another method with a more suitable signature:

```
button.Click += (s, e) => SaveDocument(someLocalVariable);
```

In that example, `someLocalVariable` is local to the method wiring up the events - it could be an instance variable of course, but then you don't really need to pass it as you'd have access anyway.

Comment: As Jon Skeet points out, there's a very direct way for that to happen.
However, I'd question why you're storing a binary array as a buttons Tag. Is there perhaps a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Get your tag like this

```
byte[] myData = ((Button)sender).Tag
```